# Override LocationManager?

Tags: java, android, locationmanager

I'd like to change the behaviour of LocationManager, but its constructor isn't visible, so Eclipse won't allow extending it.

Can it be done?

If so, how do I get around the above issue, and then, how do I instantiate it? (Or have the system use it as the LocationManager?)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the source:

```
/**
 * @hide - hide this constructor because it has a parameter
 * of type ILocationManager, which is a system private class. The
 * right way to create an instance of this class is using the 
 * factory Context.getSystemService.
 */
public LocationManager(ILocationManager service) {
    if (Config.LOGD) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Constructor: service = " + service);
    }
    mService = service;
}
```

Notice the comment. Use Context.getSystemService.